# Why does my Matrix not return any value to the screen?

Tags: c

I have been trying to solve a problem, in which the query is:

---

1. Replace each element of the main diagonal with the sum of all the elements above it (in the same column) and located right from it (in the same row)
2. Replace each element of the opposite diagonal with the sum of all the elements below it (in the same column) and located left from it (in the same row)

**My problem**: I am not sure why the program doesn't show anything after the input is done

Reading the matrix

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){

int i,j,m,k,a[100][100],new_mat[100][100];
scanf("%d%d",&m,&k); //m=rows, k=columns

for (i = 0 ; i < m ; i++)
    for (j = 0 ; j < k ; j++)
        scanf("%d", &a[i][j]);
```

// INITIAL solution, however it only covered only the first closest elements to it, rather than the sum of ALL the elements below and upwards

```
/*
for(i=0;i<m;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<k;j++)

        {
     if(i==j)
        if(j+1<k && i-1>=0)
         {a[i][j]+=a[i][j+1]+a[i-1][j];}

     if(i+j==m-1)
        if(j-1>=0 && i+1<k)
         {a[i][j]=a[i][j-1]+a[i+1][j];}
     }
}
*/
```

---

So, I tried to reach all the remaining elements with an additional for cycle

```
for(i=0;i<m;i++)

{
    for(j=0;j<k;j++)
     {
           if(i==j)
             for(;j+1<k,i-1>=0;j+1,i-1)
           {
               a[i][j]+=a[i][j+1]+a[i-1][j];
           }


           if(i+j==m-1)
            for(;j-1>=0,i+1<k;j-1,i+1)
           {
               a[i][j]=a[i][j-1]+a[i+1][j];}
           }
     }
```

---

And then printing the result:

```
for (i=0; i<m; i++)
    for(j=0; j<k; j++)
        printf("%d     ", a[i][j]);
    printf("\n");
 return 0;}
```

However, upon entering the matrix, nothing occurs and a value is not returned to the screen

Comment: "*a value is not returned to the screen*" this probably dues to no `printf()` being called. You might like to run the code using a debugger. Which in fact should be the the first steps when facing such issues anyways.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't deeply inspect the code to see if it does what you want it to do. I just looked in General.

**First**: Conventions. Please add brackets around the `for`. It will be easier to review the code.

```
       if(i+j==m-1)
       {
        for(;j-1>=0,i+1<k;j-1,i+1)
        ...
       }
```

**Second**: Both loops run forever, since you don't change j and i!
Did you mean?

```
        for(;j-1>=0,i+1<k;j--,i++)
```

**Third**: You really should learn to work with a debugger. Using proper debugger you would have found the problem in no time.